# Trouble pulling daily data - day resets at 5 PM

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to pull daily data using PostgreSQL. My problem is that the day seems to 'reset' at around 5 PM (Los Angeles Time). Is there a workaround this problem? Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct be.booking_id)AS "Number of Bookings Today"
FROM booking_events be
WHERE be.event IN ('approve') AND
      be.created_at >= current_date AND
      be.created_at < current_date + interval '1 day';
```

Comment: `current_date at time zone 'PDT'` or `be.created_at at time zone 'PDT'` depending of source of the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hours to offset the current date.  I think the logic is:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct be.booking_id) as "Number of Bookings Today"
FROM booking_events be
WHERE be.event IN ('approve') AND
      be.created_at >= current_date - interval '7 hour' AND
      be.created_at < current_date + interval '1 day' - interval '7 hour';
```

Comment: Hmmm, if you mean that `current_date` resets around 5:00 p.m. LA time (meaning that it is GST), then use `+ interval `7 hour'` instead of `-`.